# Hiding messages in Thunderbird automatically?

Tags: macos, thunderbird, tabs

Is there any way to configure Thunderbird 17 so that when read a message and then go back to the Inbox (or any of the other items in that column) the open message will close automatically?

I would love to have the message display work the way it does when I single-click and display the message in the lower half of the right window, except that I want it to fill the screen.

Comment: Please avoid comments like Thanks in a question for more information on asking see [ask]